# Does changing certificate invalidate all secret generated with IdentityServer4.Models.Secret Sha256() method?

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, sha256

I'm currently building my web application with identity server 4. I dynamically create clients with a secret generated with Sha256() method of identityserver 4.
However, i'm worrying that when i will renew or change my certificate all those secret will be invalidate which will pose a serious problem.

Are SHA256 linked with the certificat ? Or only Token will be invalidate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the signing credential used for token signing and validation has nothing to do with the hashing of secrets.